# Excel : Filling a column from another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a specific need to do with excel:
I have 2 tables as follows:

[image: TABLE 1]

[image: Table 2]

I want to automatically fill the 'COL D' with the corresponding values, referring to 'COL A' and 'COL B'.
( Note that the values in 'COL C' are the same in 'COL A')

Comment: You can use a basic [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). There are probably hundreds of examples [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bexcel%5dVLOOKUP). In cell `D2` use `=VLOOKUP($C2,$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)` and copy down.

Answer (score 0):

Try

=VLOOKUP(LOOKUPVALUE,TABLE ARRAY,COL,RANGE LOOKUP)

For you,

=VLOOKUP("Col C value", Range of ColA & ColB, 2, FALSE)
Be sure to use $ signs on the range of ColA and be for Col D.

Comment: Thanks , but I think that my Excel can't recognize this function ! I'm using Microsoft 365

Comment: I believe 365 supports a new function "XLOOKUP". I haven't used it, but should accomplish the same objective